# Full screen Windows Form goes beyond screen dimensions

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, fullscreen

I have a WinForms app (.NET 4) that needs to be shown either full screen or maximized without borders.

Using the following code in the `Form_Shown` event:

```
#if (DEBUG)
    var debug = true;
#else
    var debug = false;
#endif

this.Text = "";
this.ControlBox = false;
this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
//this.TopMost = debug;
this.TopLevel = true;
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

if (debug) { this.Bounds = Screen.FromControl(this).WorkingArea; }
else { this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized; }
```

If you look closely at the screenshot below, the top and bottom areas are cut off by a few pixels. Also, if maximized, the window still does not cover the task bar.

Please note that I have only one monitor attached. No secondary displays.

Any suggestions on how to address the two issues above would be appreciated.

[image: Screenshot of app in maximized mode]

**UPDATE:** The code above seems to work fine with forms without a `MenuStrip` or `StatusStrip`.

Comment: The TaskBar always appears on top of windows, even when it's set to Auto-Hide. Also note that according to [WorkingArea's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation, it *doesn't* take into account the size of the collapsed taskbar when in Auto-Hide mode. Are you trying to create a Kiosk application?

Comment: @utility: updated the screen shot. Open the image in full size and have a look at the top menu bar and the bottom status strip. The forms Bounds seem to start at less than zero (Y1) and seem to end at greater than the working area height (Y2).

Comment: @GrantWinney: Yes, see my comment to Reza's answer below. I had initially set the form to be maximized in the designer and forgotten to undo that.

Comment: This code belongs in the constructor, never in Shown.  Short from avoiding the very ugly flicker, you'll also avoid the nasty side-effects that these properties have.  Like jerking the floor mat on exactly what the size of a maximized window should be.

Comment: @HansPassant: THANK YOU! I hadn't realized that `FormBorderStyle` and `WindowState` properties could have such a nasty effect (even more so since I manualy layout controls through code after the constructor). Following your suggestion reduced flicker from a few seconds to virtually zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the code I use for fullscreen. I create a `FullScreen` property for my form and when I need, I set `this.FullScreen = true;`

```
private bool fullScreen = false;
[DefaultValue(false)]
public bool FullScreen
{
    get
    {
        return fullScreen;
    }
    set
    {
        fullScreen = value;

        if (value)
        {
            //this.SuspendLayout();
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            //this.ResumeLayout(true);
        }
        else
        {
            this.Activate();
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems that setting `WindowState` to `Normal` before setting `FormBorderStyle` does the trick. This is likely because the form was set to be maximized in the designer.

Comment: That's another question but suspending/resuming layout has not helped in my case. There is a lot of UI customization via code-only and lots of flicker at start up.

Comment: @RaheelKhan I didn't check its real effectiveness, but based on expectation from those methods, I used them.