# Hiding the taskbar during runtime when toggling fullscreen mode

Tags: vb.net, winforms, fullscreen, taskbar

I'm trying to make my application able to switch between fullscreen/maximized mode (fullscreen hides toolbar and taskbar while maximized shows them).

Here's my current code which accomplishes this:

```
Private Sub Form_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
End Sub

Sub fullscreen()
    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
End Sub

Sub maximized()
    FormBorderStyle.Sizable
End Sub
```

The taskbar is hidden when the form loads and is put in fullscreen. However, when calling `fullscreen` after `maximized` the taskbar doesn't hide itself again.

I've found that this is because the taskbar only hides itself when these two lines are called together:

```
FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
```

Changing `fullscreen` to:

```
Sub fullscreen()
    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
End Sub
```

doesn't quite fix this problem though.

I actually need to change it to:

```
Sub fullscreen()
    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
End Sub
```

so the Form registers that `WindowState` is changed. Unfortunately this results in an annoying flicker on the screen because of the switch between `Normal` and `Maximized`.

Could I have a suggestion which fixes this?

---

Update:

```
Sub fullscreen()
    SuspendLayout()

    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized

    ResumeLayout(True)
End Sub
```

there is now no flickering when calling `fullscreen` (On further debugging, this doesn't seem to be entirely true for some reason, though). However, this has made me realise that `maximized` also results in flickering and even:

```
Sub maximized()
    SuspendLayout()

    FormBorderStyle.Sizable

    ResumeLayout(True)
End Sub
```

won't stop it. A suggestion to fix this too please? Perhaps there is a completely different way of accomplishing fullscreen switches without the flickering?

Comment: Why do you need to make it go normal, and then Maximized?

Comment: @PhiterFernandes Otherwise the taskbar doesn't hide itself for some reason. The Form needs to register a change in WindowState to hide the taskbar I think.

Comment: You can try to change window width and height to the screen resolution when it's on normal.

Comment: [Full screen Windows Form goes beyond screen dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32821133/full-screen-windows-form-goes-beyond-screen-dimensions)

Comment: Didn't know about SuspendLayout and ResumeLayout, might be helpful.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes I didn't check effectiveness `SuspendLayout()` and `ResumeLayout` and just used them based on expectation which I had from those methods, but the `FullScreen` property works properly.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thanks for that - this stopped flickering in `fullscreen`. Now that I've tried them I've just realised that the flickering also exists in `maximized`. Even wrapping `FormBorderStyle.Sizable` with `Suspend/ResumeLayout` doesn't stop it.. and now my eyes hurt from debugging ^^'

Comment: I shared the link just for TaskBar problem. Probably `SuspendLayout` is not useful. Since the current question is about taskbar problem, I recomend you to remove the edit part and ask a new question about flickering.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I think I will. However I'll keep this question open as I'm still hoping for a better way of fixing the taskbar problem. Changing `WindowState` to `Normal` and then `Maximized` doesn't seem to be the elegant way of doing it.

Comment: OK, but about flickering it seems it's a new question. If you asked a new question, it's better to remove the edit part of this question. Now the question is somehow confusing, it contains the answer, also asked a new question in update part :)

Comment: To reduce the flicker, I override `CreateParams` and added `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` with value `0x02000000` to `ExStyle`. Also used `Suspend/ResumeLayout`. The result was better than all other options.

Comment: You may find this article useful: [How to get rid of flicker on Windows Forms applications](http://www.angryhacker.com/blog/archive/2010/07/21/how-to-get-rid-of-flicker-on-windows-forms-applications.aspx)