# How to use the escape key to control whether a form is fullscreen or not

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio, fullscreen

I am attempting to make a form in visual studio using the windows form application and designer, but when I try using the escape key to maximise/minimise and remove/add the border it does not cover all of the taskbar.

I am simply testing the functionality of being able to enter and exit fullscreen for any forms I might make in the future, so far I have tried nothing besides the code pictured, and placing the code in the case selection as a separate subroutine.

```
Public Sub FullscreenEnterExit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal d As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    Select Case d.KeyValue
        Case Keys.Escape
            If fullscreen = False Then
                Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.None
                Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(1920, 1080)
                Me.Controls.Add(Me.PictureBox1)
                Me.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
                Me.MaximumSize = New System.Drawing.Size(1920, 1080)

                Me.Name = "window"
                Me.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.Manual
                Me.Text = "Form1"
                Me.TopMost = True
                Me.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized
                CType(Me.PictureBox1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
                Me.ResumeLayout(False)
                fullscreen = True
            ElseIf fullscreen = True Then
                Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.None
                Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(1920, 1080)
                Me.Controls.Add(Me.PictureBox1)
                Me.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle
                Me.MaximumSize = New System.Drawing.Size(1920, 1080)

                Me.Name = "window"
                Me.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.Manual
                Me.Text = "Form1"
                Me.TopMost = True
                Me.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized
                CType(Me.PictureBox1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
                Me.ResumeLayout(False)
                fullscreen = False
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

I would post images of how the fullscreen looks but you need 10 reputation.
it is maximised but and covers everything but about 3/4 of the taskbar.
Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can add a picture - the post will include a link to a storage area and then a person with enough reputation will edit it in for you. Use the [edit] link under the question to add more content.

Comment: Why the Select Case when there is only one case?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32821243/4934172) for how to implement fullscreen in WinForms. It's for C# but should be easy to convert to VB.

Comment: @Mary forgot to change it

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may have difficulty following your own code because there is so much duplicate. I got rid of the Select Case. I also got rid of all the code for properties of the form that were probably set at design time.

I hope you had the PictureBox declared and instantiated elsewhere of that won't work. I would have expected the picture box would have been added at design time because it didn't seen to have anything to do with the window state.

I have no idea why you are trying to change the type of the PictureBox to interface SupportInitialization.

You have both the If and Else If setting .Maximized to True. I don't think that is what you intended.

What was ResumeLayout(False) supposed to do?

```
Public Sub FullscreenEnterExit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal d As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If d.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then
        If fullscreen Then
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        Else
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        End If
        fullscreen = Not fullscreen
    End If
End Sub
```

Set the form's KeyPreview property to True.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure of why this is, but it seemed to just be a matter of adding 
Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal on both the if and else
Thanks for the help anyhow.