# how to make fullscreen toggle button on/off

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a Win Forms project where I'm trying to create an button to toggle full screen on/off every time i click the button,so  if you click once, it becomes full screen, if you click again, it becomes normal again.
please tell me how to do that.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but should be useful. Just add a click handler. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505167/how-do-i-make-a-winforms-app-go-full-screen

Comment: i need it to load with normal mode , but when i click the button turn it to full and click it again to turn it to normal again ...etc i want the button go on/off full screen

Comment: You can use [`FullScreen`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32821243/3110834) custom property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the exact requirements but this should help you.

Add `Form1_Load` and `button1_Click` events.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Normal when the form opens
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Toggle on a button click
    WindowState = WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal ? FormWindowState.Maximized : FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```